# Using titleize for acronym in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string

I am defining some active records with acronyms. RvPark (Recreational Vehicle Park). When I titleize the class name, I get 'Rv Park'. It really should be 'RV Park'. Is there a good way to do this? Since this model shares code with other models, I need to create a generic solution, but I haven't been able to come up with one.

I did see a discussion on this, but there wasn't a solution that worked for me. any insight is appreciated.

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2944-titleize-doesnt-take-all-uppercase-words-into-account

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE: Acronym support [was added to the Rails Inflector](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/d38ca78dbd99be11e64652163924e9456a7a2362) after I posted this.

See [@Anson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22637925/199712) for Rails 3.2 and up.

---

This looks like an edge-case that `titleize` wasn't designed for. The problem is the `capitalize` call inside will always turn RV into Rv.

I would create a generic name function for the models that call `self.class.titleize` internally, and then overload it in the RVPark model.

Comment: @GabeKopley How github.com/granth/titleize gem will work for the scenario of asked question? It seems its working as normal titleize

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Acronyms are not an edge case, and `titleize` in Rails can absolutely handle them. See the answer below.

Comment: @nathan.f77 my answer was correct at the time it was written, but the Inflector was updated to support this use-case shortly afterward.

Comment: Ah right, wow I didn't see that was from 2011. Ok sorry about that :)

Comment: It's still not helpful that the wrong answer was preserved as this is the accepted answer and people will no doubt read the whole thing.

Answer (score 20):

You can do this by configuring [ActiveSupport::Inflector](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html), which provides the [titleize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-titleize) method. Simply define your own [inflections](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html) in an initializer.

```
# config/initializers/inflections.rb
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym 'RV'
end
```

Restart your app to pick up the change. Now `titleize` knows how to handle "RV". Fire up a Rails console to check it out:

```
> "RvPark".titleize
=> "RV Park"
> "rv".titleize
=> "RV"
```

See the linked docs for more cool stuff you can do with inflections.