# Ruby titleize / convert "los angeles, ca" to "Los Angeles, CA"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, formatting, string-formatting

I'm working on a project that uses locations entered by users and I'm looking for advice on how to correctly titleize a location such as "los angeles, ca".

Using Rails `titleize`, I get "Los Angeles, Ca" (note the lowercase a in Ca), which is to be expected and I'm wondering what the best way to get the correct case for the state (capitalize both letters).

Initially I thought about splitting in the last comma and capitalizing all chars of that segment and joining it back together, which I think would work fine in most cases but I'm sure there are edge cases I haven't thought of.

Has anyone done this before or have a good solution? Alternatively, if the `split` solution is the best bet, it'd be great to get some feedback indicating as such!

Comment: Are users selecting cities which are present in a table or they're free to enter anything ?

Comment: At present they're free to enter anything. Eventually we'll move to a location autocomplete but I'm looking for a fix in the meantime

Comment: by using `text-transform: capitalize` will solve your half problem, you won't have to use `titleize` for strings not containing ",".

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. That unfortunately doesn't accomplish the uppercase state abbreviation, so it ends up the same as `titleize` (Los Angeles, Ca instead of Los Angeles, CA)

Comment: `a = "Los Angeles, Ca" after using transform:capitalize`
and then 
`final_value = (a.split(",").length == 2 and a.split(",")[1].strip.length == 2 ? "#{a.split(",")[0]}, #{a.split(",")[1].strip.try(:upcase)}" : a)`

This is my suggestion, I would really appreciate if anyone else comes up with a better solution. :)

Comment: I'd be easier to read and to vote for if you'd provide this as an answer, @Gagan Gupta

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using titleize for acronym in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22637925/2483313)

Answer (score 0):

How about matching two letter codes at the end of the string? You can just match any two letter code that is an upper followed by a lower-case letter:

```
cities = [
  'Somewhere, Fo',
  'Here, Ba',
  'Los Angeles, Ca',
  'Los Angeles, CA',
  'City,In',
  'City,IN'
]

cities.each do |city|
  puts city.gsub(/([A-Z][a-z])\z/) { |match| match.upcase }
end
```

Or, if this is just for US states and since the number of those is known and limited you could just replace those.

Answer (score 0):

`a = "Los Angeles, Ca"` 
we'll be getting after using transform:capitalize on input field and then we can get :
`a.split(",").length` will tell if it contains comma separated values or not and `a.split(",")[1].strip.length == 2` will tell if the second value contains 2 characters or not after removing spaces.

`"#{a.split(",")[0]}, #{a.split(",")[1].strip.try(:upcase)}"` this will give us a desired value if both conditions are correct.

You can write it as:

`final_value = (a.split(",").length == 2 and a.split(",")[1].strip.length == 2 ? "#{a.split(",")[0]}, #{a.split(",")[1].strip.try(:upcase)}" : a)`

**OR**

`if a.split(",").length == 2 and a.split(",")[1].strip.length == 2
 final_value = "#{a.split(",")[0]}, #{a.split(",")[1].strip.try(:upcase)}"
else
 final_value = a
end`

I hope this will help, although this is not a neat solution because data isn't standardised. Still I am willing to know better solutions too.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a pattern to match the states (case insensitive):

```
states = /AL|AK|AZ|AR|CA|CO|CT|and_so_on/i
```

and replace a trailing state in the string with an [`upcase`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-upcase)-d version:

```
location = 'los angeles, ca'
location.titleize.sub(/\b#{states}\z/, &:upcase)
#=> "Los Angeles, CA"
```